# Cell profile in WebSphere

Tags: java, html, tomcat, jboss, websphere

I want to create a cell profile in WebSphere but I am not getting the options here what is wrong..
image:-
https://ibb.co/WPBYrB2

Comment: You probably have "single server" version. Check what will be shown when you select "Management". Cell profile is only available in "Network Deployment" version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have WebSphere Application Server (version not mentioned in question).You can use the Profile Management Tool that comes with IBM WebSphere installation.

Go to Windows Start > IBM WebSphere > Profile Management Tool. If you are doing this for local development, then a standalone profile needs to be created. You can refer this link for more details.[Create standalone profile](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spim/1.0.1.1?topic=tasks-creating-stand-alone-profiles-profile-management-tool)